# Difference between "work like a dream" and "work like magic"

Tags: idioms

Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms '***work like a dream***' and '***work like magic***'? The definitions in the Cambridge Dictionary are:

**- work like magic**: to be very effective, possibly in a surprising way

**- work/go like a dream**: to work or go extremely well, without any problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt many (if any) people would interpret an utterance differently depending on whether it included *[worked] **like a dream*** or ***like magic***. But it's worth noting that neither version is [anywhere near as common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=worked%20like%20a%20charm%2Cworked%20like%20a%20dream%2Cworked%20like%20magic&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) as ***like a charm***...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary does show the difference: *in a surprising way*.
In both cases the result was good; the difference is in the expectation.

- like magic – possible snags and problems didn't happen
- like a dream – just as hoped for